# How to create localhost domain management for windows in php?

Tags: java, php, apache, localhost, virtualhost

I am crazy about this thing, but i want to make it myself in php itself.

I have installed the following in my system.

**WAMP Server 2.2 which includes following**

- Apache Web Server Version 2.2.222
- MySQL Server Version 5.5.24
- PHP Version 5.3.13
- OS Version Windows 8 64Bit

**Location of Hosts file:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

**Location of WAMP Server:**

```
C:\wamp
```

**Location of Apache Web Server:**

```
 - C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22

 - C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Location of MySQL Server:**

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24
```

**Location of PHP:**

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
```

I have simple example of Create the VHost in **`localhost`**
e.g. I want to create simple domain **www.mylocalsite.com** on **80** port

**For that I have following steps:**

**(1) Enagle Apache modules**

- rewrite_module
- vhosts_alias_module

**(2) Open httpd.conf file to enable Vhost settings**

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf
```

## Virtual hosts

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf // Remove the # before Include and save file
```

**(3) Add VHost entry in httpd-vhosts.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
   DocumentRoot "C:/mylocalsite.com/"
   ServerName www.mylocalsite.com

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:/mylocalsite.com/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog "C:/mylocalsite.com/logs/error.log"   // Logs folder should be exists
   CustomLog "C:/mylocalsite.com/logs/access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

**(4) Add entry in hosts file**
Open file in Notepad with Admin Permission **C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts**
add following line at end of the file and Save it.

```
127.0.0.1    www.mylocalsite.com
```

**(5) Restart the (From WAMP) Apache Web Server and run in browser** **http://www.mylocalsite.com/** will work.

Now, My Question is how can I do the above steps in dynamic nature using ***PHP/JSP or any other language***.

Suppose I will create one Form in HTML with following fields and when submit it will create new MySQL entry for that domain.

**EDIT:**

```
Domain Type: select option or Radio Options ( Root/Sub-Domain )
Sub-Domain Name ( Optional ): Text field
Domain Name: Text field
Project Path: text field
Log Folder Path: text field
Tmp Folder Path: text field
Database Type: text field ( mysql/pgsql )
<Submit>
```

when i click on  button it will automatically create the domain entry in **hosts** file, **vhosts** entry in **httpd-vhosts.conf** file.

And, when restart the Apache server it will run automatically created domain or sub-domain dynamically.

Can anyone knows how can i established the following things in any language for local system only?

Comment: It's a good initiation to develop like hosting environment in local machine.

Comment: Yes it is also useful for those user who don't know how to create in local envirenment.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use web form. You can see my demo with batch file:

**(1) Create vhost template template.txt**

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
DocumentRoot "_ROOT_"
ServerName _DOMAIN_

# This should be omitted in the production environment
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<Directory "_ROOT_">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog "_ROOT_/logs/error.log"// Logs folder should be exists
CustomLog "_ROOT_/logs/access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

**(2) Create add_vhost.bat**

```
@echo off  
set /p domain=Domain (www.mylocalsite2.com):   
set lineHost=127.0.0.1 %domain%  

REM Create the domain entry in hosts file  
echo %lineHost% >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  

set /p folder=Folder (C:/mylocalsite2.com/):   
REM Create vhost entry in httpd-vhosts.conf file  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (template.txt) do (  
    set str=%%i  
    set str=!str:_ROOT_=%folder%!  
    set str=!str:_DOMAIN_=%domain%!  
    echo !str! >> C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf  
)
```

**(3) Run add_vhost.bat as Administrator (to write HOSTS file)**

Comment: Wow that is amazing thing in answer gven by you. I will try and implement. This thing will add new entey in both files. If I want to update any vhost entry or disable/delete same thing will be apply or I should change in a way that find host in a file and replace existing vhost entry.

Comment: As I think we need Admin Permission to access / write in hosts file. so, any solution for that.

Comment: I think I have to give user permission to admin interface where user can set permission to access the System Resources and admin Run the Batch File / SH File in Windows/Linux Respectively.

Comment: Should I need to create Batch file which can be run by authenticated users in background while generating new Domain from HTML Interface?

Comment: The first part (modifying the hosts file) worked fine. Thanks. But the second part (the template and the vhosts) didn't work for me. I don't know why